# Flask JSON Parsing

Tags: python, json, flask

```
def api_all():
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route('/api/', methods=['GET'])
def api_id():
    if('id' in request.args and 'key' in request.args):
        id = int(request.args['id'])
        key = str(request.args['key'])
    else:
        return "Error: Missing argument."

    results = []

    for user in data["users"]: # Error from here
        print(user)
        if(user['id'] == id and user['key'] == key):
            results.append(user)
    return jsonify(results)
app.run()
```

There is my main code.

```
  "users": [
    {
      "id":"0",
      "name":"Jane",
      "balance":"100$",
      "key":"byt3dsz69pl0hmb"
    },
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"John",
      "balance":"100$",
      "key":"z0apdio4bvn549e"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is data.json or, the data variable. I cannot get this to work, I get the following error:

> TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

I am building a basic api to get account balances, this is juts for educational purposes so it does not have to be secure. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have used flask before but I can never get my head around how JSON works with python, I find it quite hard to understand.

Comment: Please show where `data` is getting its value.

Comment: `
with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
`

Comment: Just fixed a typo, in my open code, I no longer get an error but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code snippet converts `id` from the request to an int, but the value of the `id` key in the JSON is a string.  Since

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
>>>
```

you'll to make the types match before you can compare them.